# How do I use rigidbody2d.AddForce to apply a force in the direction the object is facing?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I'm trying to create a thruster on a spaceship.  It should add this thrust in the direction the thruster is facing, but I am at a loss on how to get that direction and send it to AddForce.  Am I even heading in the right direction with this script?

```
public float maxThrust;
FixedUpdate()
{
 float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * maxThrust; 
 Vector3 heading = rigidbody2D.transform.eulerAngles; 
 Vector2 thrust = new Vector2(heading.normalized.x, heading.normalized.z); 
 rigidbody2D.AddForce(thrust * moveVertical);
}
```

Maybe I'm not understanding something with EulerAngles or Vectors, but it sure seems like this would be a straightforward thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rigidbody2D's transform has **up**, **right**, and **forward** properties that'll tell you what's up, right, or forward for the object, respectively. In 2D, only two of those will actually be useful to you, and I imagine those would be **up** and **right**.

So, if you want to apply the force in the object's **up** direction, do away with `Vector3 heading = ...;` and calculate thrust something like this instead:

`var thrust = transform.up;`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That works beautifully, thank you!  I'm glad it really is that simple.

Comment: Glad I could help! Unity's got a *lot* of helpful properties and methods to help with vector maths and angles.